# In Simplesamlphp The IdP should check which NameIDFormat the SP requests, and try to send back that format

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have configured multiple SP in saml20-sp-hosted.php , i want one of my SP to use mail attribute as nameid.

saml20-sp-hosted.php

`$metadata['entityId1'] = array (
    'entityid1' => 'entityId',
    'contacts' =>
    array (
    0 =>
    array (
    'contactType' => 'technical',
    'givenName' => 'XXX',
    'surName' => 'XXX',
    'emailAddress' =>
    array (
    0 => 'XXX@YYY.com',
     ),
     ),
     ),
    'metadata-set' => 'saml20-sp-remote',
    'attributes' => array('mail', 'sn', 'givenName', 'uid'),
    'AssertionConsumerService' =>
    array (
     0 =>
      array (
     'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
     'Location' => 'http://www.XXXYYY.com/SSO/ACS.aspx',
     'index' => 0,
      ),
     ),
     'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
    );`
 
for given above SP i want to use "mail" attribute as nameid but i have defined 'uid' attribute in given below idp file so it is overwriting the attribute.
If i am trying to overwrite with 'mail' attribute in saml20-sp-hosted.php file it is posting transient nameid.

saml20-idp-hosted.php

```
   'authproc' => array(

    3 => array(
      'class' => 'saml:AttributeNameID',
      'attribute' => 'uid',
      'Format' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
    ),
       50 => array(
           'class' => 'core:AttributeMap',
              'mail' => 'Email',
              'sn' => 'Lastname',
              'givenName' => 'Firstname',
             // 'memberOf' => 'Groups',
              'uid' => 'Username'
    //'cn' => array('name', 'displayName', 'sn'),
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your IdP side file is saml20-idp-hosted.php, not saml20-sp-remote.php?